# Funny behavior when integrating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-review

Having the defined the following:

```
    gamma = x;
lw=8;

    Proietto[a_, b_] := Integrate[a b, {x, 0, lw}, Assumptions -> u > 0];
    jtor = (9*(6/5 - x/20)^3)/
        1150 + ((3519*(6/5 - x/20)*(-HeavisideTheta[-38/5 + x] + 
               HeavisideTheta[-32/5 + x]))/
           20000 + (207*(6/5 - x/20)*(HeavisideTheta[-38/5 + x] - 
               HeavisideTheta[-32/5 + x] + HeavisideTheta[x]))/
           1000)*((6421*(6/5 - x/20)*(-HeavisideTheta[-38/5 + x] + 
                HeavisideTheta[-32/5 + x]))/
            434000 + (11*(6/5 - x/20)*(HeavisideTheta[-38/5 + x] - 
                HeavisideTheta[-32/5 + x] + HeavisideTheta[x]))/50)^2;
    gtaglio = 2.59203007518797*^10;
```

I wish to integrate the following:

```
-Proietto[gtaglio D[jtor, {x, 1}] D[phi gamma, {x, 1}], gamma]
```

Yet it doesn't work (stays non-evaluated). Instead, and this is the funny behavior mentioned, this works:

```
-gtaglio Proietto[D[jtor, {x, 1}] D[phi gamma, {x, 1}], gamma]
```

Why??? It is only a question of multiplying the argument of the integral by a numerically defined constant. Could this be a wicked bug?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the integral is not evaluated in either case for me.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I forgot to define lw. Pardon me. Now the second case should work fine (not the first case!)

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a bug.

Comment: would recommend not mixing approximate numbers with a symbolic integral, especially one that handles "jump" distributions such as `DiracDelta` and `HeavisideTheta`. If intermediate processing uses e.g. `Together` then the approximate numbers can appear in various places that might make the singular points impossible to find.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Update. I've tried by rationalizing the constant gtaglio firstly, but still this doesn't work.